# Validação de Tamanho de Imagem

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Estou tentando usar o plugin jQuery Validate para validar um campo `file`.

Eu só quero verificar o tamanho da imagem. Se for maior que 3mb não é para submeter o formulário.

Vejam meu código abaixo:

```
$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size >= param) 
});

if($("#form-ouvidoria")[0]){
   $("#form-ouvidoria").validate({
      rules             : {
        assunto         : "required",
        departamento    : "required",
        mensagem        : "required",
        field: { 
            required: true, 
            extension: "png|jpe?g|gif", 
            filesize: 3145728
        }
      },
      submitHandler: function(form){
        $("#enviaChamado").attr('disabled', 'true');
        $('span.loading').css('opacity', '1');
        form.submit();
      }
   });
}
```

Mas quando selecione uma imagem maior que 3mb e aperto em enviar dá o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element , check the 'extension' method.

Comment: Que tipo de aplicação  "IDE" vc esta usando?

Comment: Como assim, @MarconcilioSouza ?

Comment: Seu `jQuery` , vc esta usando em uma pagina `aspx`, `php` ... `html` .....

Comment: E o que a linguagem server-side influencia nisso ?

Comment: Não influência nada na resposta, era só uma duvida minha... mas como vc já tem a resposta blz.

Comment: É em PHP que eu programo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrigido.
Eu não sabia, mas encontrei na internet que deve-se importar o seguinte arquivo:

`jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js`

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso o [jQuery FileUpload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) para fazer isso. Nativamente ele já tem essa validação, e alguns outros recursos bacanas.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i, // tipo de arquivos
    maxFileSize: 512000 // tamanho maximo
    [...]
});
```

Comment: Top, mas é só para arquivo ? Porque o jQuery Validate eu uso para formulários. É muito bom tambénhê!

Comment: @TaoPaiPai, o Fileupload é só para arquivos, apesar que ele possui eventos para tratar ao adicionar arquivos, ou antes de iniciar upload. E nesse momento vc pode chamar o jQuery Validade. Ou usar junto o unobtrusive, que gosto muito.

Comment: Quem deu downgrade, pode justificar?

Comment: Eu não me justifico quando voto down. Mas não fui, eu dei voto up na sua resposta, se quiser te mando print, imprimo, scaneio, registro em cartório e te mando...

Comment: @Zooboomafoo haha, nao precisa. Eu so gostaria de saber, de quem negativou, o motivo. Pois as vezes eu realmente respodi algo errado, e gostaria de aprender tbm. Mas obrigado pelo retorn.